# Jquery equivalent for every in mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

In Mootools you have an array method called `every`. It's descripton is:

> Returns true if every element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. This method is provided only for browsers without native Array:every support.

As an example code:

```
var bAdd = this.selectList.getElements('li').every(
                    function(elm) {
                        return (elm.id != this.id);
                    }, option);
```

What would be the equivalent in jquery? I guess not each?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no inbuilt support for this.

Assuming `this.selectList` is an dom element reference

```
var $lis = $(this.selectList).find('li');
var bAdd = $lis.filter($.proxy(function(elm) {
    return (elm.id != this.id);
}, option)).length == $lis.length;
```

Comment: you can also use $.grep though im not sure it makes a difference

Comment: @DGS if you have an array you can use $.grep since here we might be looking at a jQuery element set `filter` is the best fit

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function is what you want.

```
$("li").each(function(i, el) {
 ...
});
```

Comment: more generally http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ which allows iteration over non jQuery objects

Comment: @DGS thats not true. jQuery objects are equivalently iterated through `.each()`.

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj no it is not what the OP wants, he want either true or false as the result

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj the documentation you linked to was for the $.each function which as it says on the page you linked is different from http://api.jquery.com/each/ which is the $(ele).each function